# Trying to refer a project not mentioned in .classpath

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, eclemma

I am trying to setup EclEmma Code coverage in my eclipse. When I am trying to run JUNIT4 from "Coverage As" I am getting an error.

> SOME_PRE_EXISTED_JAR_I_HAD-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar which is referenced by the classpath does not exist

I have verified the .classpath of the project but the jar is not mentioned there. Also checked all the dependent project classpath as well. Tried clean and fresh build also.

Is there any master .classpath file which I need to edit?

Comment: Maven support usually resets your build path.  Any reason you cannot put that jar file in a repository accessible to Maven? (install:install-file can help)

Comment: deleting the .classpath file and again clean build solved the issue. Even though the initial classpath file had no reference to the jar.